# onActivityResult to handle both facebook and twitter login

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

In facebook, Im asked to do:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In Twitter, Im asked to do:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How to combine them, and what is onActivityResult used for? To tell button text to change to ":logout"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is Identify `onActivityResult` on **requestCode**

See this link for [Twitter Request code](https://twittercommunity.com/t/android-twitter-requestcode-in-onactivityresult/38592/2?u=solo4solo)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == TwitterAuthConfig.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE){
        //  twitter related handling
    }else{
       // facebook related handling
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the method called after executing an Intent which your app would call. For example, a facebook login is initiated by your app, this method gets called for whatever happened to the facebook login (Failed, Cancelled etc.). When executing an intent you get to pass a Request Code to the Intent parameters the same request code is then passed to this `onActivityResult` method. You can use this request code to determine which results are the intent data received from (whether from facebook or twitter or others.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!